# How to get thumbnail image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, css, output, thumbnails

I have code something like this,

```
$output .= '<div class="feature-course" '.$style.'>';
                $output .= '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink(). '">' . get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';      
                $output .= '<p>' . the_excerpt_max_charlength(70). '</p>';      
                $output .= '<a class="btn-featue" href="' . get_permalink(). '">' . __('View Course', 'themeum-lms'). ' <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>';
```

I need to add image function how I can do that? Can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$output .= '<div class="feature-course" '.$style.'>';
$output .= '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink(). '">' . get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';  

//Display Full image thubnail with link 
$output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'full').'</a>';

// Retrieve Thumbnail URL and use it on src attribute
$output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url(  get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) ).'" alt="Yow" title="Yow" /></a>';

$output .= '<p>' . the_excerpt_max_charlength(70). '</p>';      
$output .= '<a class="btn-featue" href="' . get_permalink(). '">' . __('View Course', 'themeum-lms'). ' <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
get_the_post_thumbnail ( int $post_id = null, string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', string|array $attr = '' )
```

More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ); ?>

<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1 ); ?>

<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code for getting thumbnail image.

```
the_post_thumbnail(); // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) ); // Other resolutions
```

For more please referhttps://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

==========================

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
   $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
   echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
   echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
   echo '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct function to use, since the OP is concatenating strings (as `the_post_thumbnails()` echoes the thumbnail).